# How to preserve scatter plot series colors in the legend in matlab 2015B?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

The following matlab code

```
h1=scatter([1:10],[1:10],'red');
hold on;
h2=scatter([1:10],[2:11],'blue');
legend([h1;h2]);
```

used to generate two entries in the legend, one red, the other blue in Matlab 2014A. In Matlab 2015B, both entries now appear in blue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is a known [bug](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1283854) for this release, i.e. legend colors in scatter plots don't fit.

If you click the link you can download a patch from the Mathworks to fix the problem.

As a workaround, you can assign the `MarkerEdgeColor` of each scatter plot to its associated `CData`, or any RGB triplet after generating the scatter plots:

```
h1=scatter([1:10],[1:10],'r');
hold on;
h2=scatter([1:10],[2:11],'blue');

h1.MarkerEdgeColor = h1.CData;
h2.MarkerEdgeColor = h2.CData;

%// or -----\\%
%//  h1.MarkerEdgeColor = [1 0 0];
%//  h2.MarkerEdgeColor = [0 0 1];
%//----------\\%

legend([h1;h2],'Location','NorthWest');
```

Output:

[image]